# Programmaticallly generate grids in Stack Panel (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, wordpress, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I have code to download data from WordPress

Here it is:

```
private async void Down_at_Start() {

        RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v1/", "ck_9d64c027d2c5f81b8bed3342eeccc6d337be813d", "cs_60697b1e6cbdeb8d62d19e0765e339f8e3334754");
        WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
        //Get all products
        var orders = await wc.GetOrders();
        string date = orders[0].date_created + "+0:00";
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date);
        string convertedDate = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        try
        {
            date1.Text = convertedDate;

            adress1.Text = orders[0].shipping.address_1.ToString() + "                     " + orders[0].shipping.address_2;

            name1.Text = orders[0].billing.first_name.ToString();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);

        }

        string date_2 = orders[1].date_created + "+0:00";
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(date_2);
        string convertedDate2 = dt2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        try
        {
            date2.Text = convertedDate2;

            adress2.Text = orders[1].shipping.address_1.ToString() + "                     " + orders[1].shipping.address_2;
            name2.Text = orders[1].billing.first_name.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);

        }

        string date_3 = orders[2].date_created + "+0:00";
        DateTime dt3 = DateTime.Parse(date_3);
        string convertedDate3 = dt3.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        try
        {
            date3.Text = convertedDate3;

            adress3.Text = orders[2].shipping.address_1.ToString() + "                     " + orders[2].shipping.address_2;
            name3.Text = orders[2].billing.first_name.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
        string date_4 = orders[3].date_created + "+0:00";
        DateTime dt4 = DateTime.Parse(date_4);
        string convertedDate4 = dt4.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        try
        {
            date4.Text = convertedDate4;

            adress4.Text = orders[3].shipping.address_1.ToString() + "                     " + orders[3].shipping.address_2;
            name4.Text = orders[3].billing.first_name.ToString();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);

        }

        string date_5 = orders[4].date_created + "+0:00";
        DateTime dt5 = DateTime.Parse(date_5);
        string convertedDate5 = dt5.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        try
        {
            date5.Text = convertedDate5;

            adress5.Text = orders[4].shipping.address_1.ToString() + "                     " + orders[4].shipping.address_2;
            name5.Text = orders[4].billing.first_name.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }



    }
```

As you see I have static number of fields.

My XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="Milano.InWork"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Milano"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Images/Background.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="720" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" BorderBrush="#FFF5F1F1" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
        <Button x:Name="MenuButton" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="38" Width="38">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="Images/Menu-100.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="logoutbutton" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,650,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="43" Width="38">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="Images/Logout_Button.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="63,2,-121,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1338" BorderBrush="#FFFDFDFD" Padding="0,0,0,1" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="В Работе" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="37" Width="1218" FontSize="32" FontFamily="SF UI Display" Padding="550,0,0,0" Foreground="White"/>
    </Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="668" Margin="63,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350">
        <StackPanel Height="1020" Width="350" BorderBrush="#FFFDFCFC" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
            <Grid Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="date1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="adress1" TextAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,146,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="name1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,86,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="date2" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" Foreground="White" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="adress2" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,145,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="59" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="name2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,87,-1,0" TextAlignment="Center"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,50"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="date3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" Foreground="White" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="adress3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,143,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="61" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="name3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,86,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,50"/>

            </Grid>
            <Grid Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="date4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" Foreground="White" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light"  />
                <TextBlock x:Name="adress4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,153,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="61" Width="342" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="name4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,86,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,50"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="date5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" Width="350" Height="50" Foreground="White" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="adress5" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,155,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="49" Width="349" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White"  />
                <TextBlock x:Name="name5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,86,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,50"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>



</Grid>
```

How I can count how many orders in answer from website and generate grids?

Thank's for help so much! :)

Comment: Leverage the power of XAML, use **Data Binding** instead.

Comment: Maybe you can provide links? You comment not help @MikeEason

Comment: It's quite a broad subject but here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuJZrLkKGUw) which explains how to bind a collection to a `ListView` in UWP.

Comment: I don't have ListView, I have stack Panel@Mike

Comment: You cannot bind a collection directly to a `StackPanel`, however you can use a `ItemsControl` and set it's `ItemsPanel` property to be a `StackPanel`. Check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(v=vs.110).aspx) and check out [this tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) (Scroll down to *"The ItemsPanelTemplate property"*).

Comment: Didn't you ask (and delete) the same question yesterday ?

Comment: yes, but I didn't get answer. now i get it @Bart